# How to switch between RecyclerView & ListView in single activity with two buttons clicks?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I've been searching so long to figure out how to switch between RecyclerView & ListView in single activity in Android. (Same way Instagram has implemented in my profile activity to view our own posts. It changes the layout of single activity to and from RecyclerView & ListView). Unfortunately I didn't find any articles or video tutorials related to it. I know asking this type of question is so amateur but any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: RecyclerView is just and 'improved' version of listView, could you clarify what do you want to do? Just migrate from listview to recyclerview in your code or some other stuff?

Comment: I think you are not understanding correctly what Instagram is doing under the hood...

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right you want to switch from a grid layout to a horizontal list layout as in instagram. You can achive the same thing using LayoutManager in a single RecyclerView
for example on button click

```
ivSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(gridShowing) {
                gridShowing=false;
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ResultsActivity.this));

                ivSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grid);
            }

            else {
                gridShowing=true;
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(ResultsActivity.this, 2));
                ivSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list);
            }

        }
    });
```

where ivSwitch is a button and  gridshowing  is a boolean with default value false. try and let me know if you need further help.